# Combine mutliple predictions

Tags: probability, classification, ensemble-learning, weighted-mean, forecast-combination

This question had been asked several times in here, but I think I have something new to add.

I'm interested in predicting if some specific event will happen (binary classification). I have two distinct methods that generate a prediction about it. The first methods, an XGBoost model, gives a binary response and the probability of the event (as the probability of being in that class). The second method is an empirical model that has as output a binary classification, but with I can estimate the probability of event given the classification.

Now, the question is, how to combine the two?

My proposal, and here is where I think I didn´t saw anything similar, is the following:

if both classifiers agree on prediction, then that's the prediciton.
When they disagree, I want to compute the weighted probability of event, where I will give more weights to extreme probabilities. The logic is that there is more information in a classifier that tells you there is a 90% or a 1% change of event compared to one that says 50%.

To do that I compute the weight $w_i$ as $|\ln\frac{p_i}{1-p_i}|$, with $p_i$ as the probability of event. What do you think

Comment: I think thats an interesting question, especially because the prediction itself is binary.  If i understand your approach right, it would mean, that each time model1 gets a weight of > 1 it takes the "win" and if it gets a weight < 1 model 2 takes the win. If im right the breakingpoint towards model 1 should be between probability 0.73 and 0.74. Is this what you want to archive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there is more information in a classifier that tells you there is a 90% or a 1% change of event compared to one that says 50%

Why do you think so?

If one classifier outputs more extreme probabilities, that first of all indicates that it is more *confident*. This certainly does not indicate that it is better. I can easily build you an extremely confident classifier that is extremely bad! (Simply output "probabilites" of 0% or 100% at random.)

The goal of any probabilistic classifier should be good calibration: when it outputs a 90% chance that a case belongs to class A, it should in fact be A in 90% of cases. If it is A in 85% or in 95% of cases, then the classifier is just as poorly calibrated as if it output 50% probability but was correct only in 45% or 55% of cases. Take a look at proper [scoring-rules](/questions/tagged/scoring-rules) to assess calibration.

That said, of course your particular problem and classifier could be improved by such a scheme. That is an empirical question. I would just be careful about claiming that higher confidence implies higher competence. That simply doesn't work. Neither for classifiers nor for humans.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Indeed, more extreme probabilities just reflect degree of confidence, which might not be correlated with competence (for both, yes :) ). However, my point was, if I trust both my classifiers equally, does it make sense to give more weight to the more confident one?

Comment: It does make sense if your more confident classifier is actually better, as per my last paragraph. I don't see a principled reason why your approach should work or not. Just try it with a large enough holdout set, against simple alternatives like unweighted combinations (which are often better than estimating "optimal" weights, which has been called the "forecast combination puzzle").